# Finding last column value for 1000+ different sized columns (excel)

Tags: excel

I have data that has different number of rows per column, and I have about 1000+ columns. I need the last value of the column, that would be my closing price then. But I have tried almost everything and I get zeros or I get the same values repeated! I am using `Excel 2016`

Maybe I'm lazy but I do not want to do this manual D:

What I have tried:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A) 

=INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A))
```

And everything else that I could find online!

**About the data:** The column vectors contain numbers that are larger than zero, and there are no empty cells in between.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

This question was solved!!! See the comments for the answer

Comment: Do you want a separate value **for each column** or do you want the value at the bottom of the **longest column**??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes i want a seperate value for each column.

Comment: And @pnuts thank you!!! I see what I did wrong all along. I had to paste that in the first row but I kept posting in the last rows. Saved me so much time xD